# OnTouchEvent not working as intended in Android

Tags: java, android

the problem is is that the touchX and Y are not saving the value taken on ACTION.DOWN, how to keep this last values? I wan to be able to draw a single line with coordinates from ACTION.DOWN to ACTION.U

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
 //detect user touch
    float touchX = 0;// I've try = event.getX();
    float touchY= 0;// = event.getY();
    float upX = 0;// = event.getX();
    float upY = 0;// = event.getX();

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        //case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchX = event.getX();
            touchY = event.getY();
            drawCanvas.drawText("x:"+ touchX + " ,y:"+ touchY,touchX, touchY, canvasPaint);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //skip
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            drawCanvas.drawText("x2:"+ touchX + " ,y2:"+ touchY,upX, upY, canvasPaint);
            drawCanvas.drawLine(touchX, touchY, upX, upY, drawPaint);
            //the problem is is that the touchX and Y are not saving the value taken on ACTION.DOWN, how to keep this last values? 
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that every time onTouch is called, you declare touchX and touchY as new variables. Answer of @Jordi would help you.

Comment: Hi Goltsev, thanks for the information. So java always runs all code everytime? because actually it returns to the value declared (e.g. touchX = 0) I made a small flowchart for this: https://www.processon.com/view/link/58f76f61e4b0f563a7f61570

Comment: Yes, on every touch (ACTION_DOWN, MOVE, UP etc.) you declare touchX and touchY again, so they are zero. Just make them as fields, i.e. put outside the onTouch method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the values you must add the method variables as object attributes, if your method is just what you posted, you just need `touchX` and `touchY`:

```
public class YourView extends View {
    // class attributes   
    float touchX = 0;
    float touchY= 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //detect user touch        
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            // your logic using touchX and touchY now 
            // will keep values assigned here
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to use it more than once, you can create your own class to save coordinates:

```
class MyPoint {
    private float x;
    private float y;

    public MyPoint(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(float x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(float y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "x:"+ x + " ,y:"+ y;
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
public class YourView extends View {
    // class attributes   
    private MyPoint touchPoint;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchPoint = new MyPoint(event.getX(), event.getY());
                drawCanvas.drawText(touchPoint.toString(), canvasPaint);
                break;

            // more!!!
```

Comment: Hi Jordi, thank you very much for this clear suggestion.